# Can't seem my datepicker to display on certain pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason the datepicker on my website isn't working on all pages.
If you click on the calendar icon [here](http://thestrandreservation.spin-demo.com/), you'll see the datepicker appearing like it's supposed to.

However, when you fill in the data and hit the submit button, you'll be taken to the next page.
On that page there's a calendar icon as well but for some reason clicking on that one doesn't do anything. I can't figure out what is causing.

Here's the errors the console is throwing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
  writeBottomBarnormaldhtmlgoodies_calendar.js:717
  initCalendarnormaldhtmlgoodies_calendar.js:773
  displayCalendarnormaldhtmlgoodies_calendar.js:811
  (anonymous function)/?ptype=user_booking:150
  onclick
```

file: [dhtmlgoodies_calendar.js](http://thestrandreservation.spin-demo.com/wp-content/themes/HotelBooking/js/normaldhtmlgoodies_calendar.js)

Comment: Is there anything similar between those four lines?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undestand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 717

```
bottomString = bottomString.replace('[monthString]',monthArrayShort[d.getMonth()]);
```

`monthArrayShort` is not defined.

---

They are not the same -- the first page include the following js file which is not in the 2nd page.

http://thestrandreservation.spin-demo.com/wp-content/themes/HotelBooking/js/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.js

Comment: How do I fix the problem though? Because the thing works on the first page but not on the second :/ There's no difference of code in like 717 between the 2 pages.